# Почему массив ведет себя как объект?

Tags: javascript

Почему массив `stage.days` возвращает длину 0, но итерация по нему идёт как по объекту? Его тип `Array` с длиной 0.

```
var stage = {
    days: []
};

stage.days['11-2']= [];
stage.days['11-3']= [];

alert(stage.days.length);  // 0

for(var it in stage.days){
    debugger // stage.days['11-2']
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос дают следующие две статьи:

[Массивы с числовыми индексами](https://learn.javascript.ru/array)

> Массив – разновидность объекта, которая предназначена для хранения
> пронумерованных значений и предлагает дополнительные методы для
> удобного манипулирования такой коллекцией.

[Работа с объектами в JavaScript: теория и практика](https://habrahabr.ru/post/48542/)

> В JavaScript есть 6 базовых  — это Undefined (обозначающий отсутствие значения), Null,  (булев тип),  (строка), Number (число) и Object (объект).
>
> При этом первые 5 являются примитивными типами данных, а Object — нет. Кроме того, условно можно считать, что у типа Object есть «подтипы»: массив (Array), функция (Function), регулярное выражение (RegExp) и другие.
> Это несколько упрощенное описание, но на практике обычно достаточное.

И простой эксперимент:

```
console.log(typeof []);
// "object"
```

---

Дополнительно прочитайте статью "[Наследование классов в JavaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/class-inheritance)". Там как раз рассмотрен случай наследования Array от Object.

---

Не менее полезно будет прочитать статью "[Объекты как ассоциативные массивы](https://learn.javascript.ru/object)" (спасибо [@AlexKrass](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16416/alex-krass) за наводку).

Comment: Наверное стоит добавить про прототипное наследование, вместо "подтипы", что тоже верно, но не в духе JS.

Comment: @Other, это цитата из статьи, а не мои слова. К тому же, это, на мой взгляд, излишне усложнит ответ. Я добавил ссылку на статью по этой теме с разобранным примером наследования массива от объекта.

Comment: This is хорошо, я доволен. А усложнит... это ТС задал хороший вопрос, не про гулопроблему, а про внутреннюю кухню JS. Значит хочет узнать больше. Значит лишняя ссылка будет в плюс.

Comment: Я думаю сюда еще хорошо зайдет тема про [ассоциативные массивы и их имитация в JS через объекты](https://learn.javascript.ru/object)

Comment: @AlexKrass, спасибо, дополнил ответ